# Is it possible to specify a data frequency when using pandas to read from an online data source?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Using the [pandas.io.data.DataReader](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/remote_data.html) class, I can read directly from online data sources like [FRED](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/):

```
import datetime
import pandas.io.data

t1 = datetime.datetime(1960, 1, 1)
t2 = datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1)

gdp = pandas.io.data.DataReader("GDPC96", "fred", t1, t2)

print(gdp.tail())
```

This fetches the data properly:

```
               GDPC96
DATE                 
2013-04-01  15606.591
2013-07-01  15779.938
2013-10-01  15916.208
2014-01-01  15831.652
2014-04-01  16010.405
```

However, these data don't actually have any frequency associated with them, so `gdp.index.freq` is just `None`. I can't set the frequency using `gdp.asfreq("Q")` for some reason, maybe because the dates are the first day of the first month of each quarter instead of the last day of the last month. If I try this:

```
print(gdp.asfreq("Q").tail())
```

I get this:

```
            GDPC96
2013-03-31     NaN
2013-06-30     NaN
2013-09-30     NaN
2013-12-31     NaN
2014-03-31     NaN
```

Is my only option to somehow remap the dates after downloading, or is there a way to download these data directly using the proper frequency, e.g. by specifying a date range (`t = pandas.date_range(t1, t2, freq="Q")`)?

Right now I'm using this method:

```
import datetime
import pandas.io.data
import scipy

t1 = datetime.datetime(1960, 1, 1)
t2 = datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1)

t = pandas.date_range(t1, t2 + datetime.timedelta(days=32), freq="Q")

gdp = pandas.io.data.DataReader("GDPC96", "fred", t1, t2)
print(gdp.tail())    

gdp.index = t
print(gdp.tail())
```

which performs the mapping correctly:

```
               GDPC96
DATE                 
2013-04-01  15606.591
2013-07-01  15779.938
2013-10-01  15916.208
2014-01-01  15831.652
2014-04-01  16010.405

               GDPC96
2013-06-30  15606.591
2013-09-30  15779.938
2013-12-31  15916.208
2014-03-31  15831.652
2014-06-30  16010.405
```

but I feel like there should be a standard way (maybe this is it) because this is probably a common operation.

update: based on the answer, I used this code:

```
import datetime
import pandas.io.data
import pandas.tseries.offsets

t1 = datetime.datetime(1960, 1, 1)
t2 = datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 1)

gdp = pandas.io.data.DataReader("GDPC96", "fred", t1, t2)
gdp.index += pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()
```

which gives me an error when I run it in Spyder (or from the command line):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-0ac9a29f7f6a>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:\folder\plots.py', wdir='C:\folder')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 585, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 48, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/folder/plots", line 10, in <module>
    gdp.index += pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 950, in __add__
    return Index(self.view(np.ndarray) + other)

TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your method is about as good as it gets. In Pandas version 0.15 or
newer, you could instead use

```
import pandas.tseries.offsets as offsets
gdp.index += offsets.QuarterEnd()
```

which results in

```
In [75]: gdp.index
Out[75]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[1960-03-31, ..., 2014-06-30]
Length: 218, Freq: Q-DEC, Timezone: None
```

---

In version 0.14, you could use

```
gdp.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(gdp.index) + offsets.QuarterEnd()
```

instead.

Comment: When I do `gdp.index += pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterEnd()` (immediately after using `pandas.io.data.DataReader`), I get this error: `TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O')`. What am I missing?

Comment: Hm, I'm not able to reproduce that error. What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: pandas 0.14.1, with Python 3.4.1 (packaged with Anaconda 2.0.1) on Windows 7 x64. I'll edit my question with a code sample too.

Comment: Sorry. Without realizing it, I was taking advantage of a recent [change to the Pandas API](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8227).